# How To Get First Index Of Multidimentional Array In VB.Net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

Sorry I'm new in .Net and it seems that vb.net kinda different while treating array.
For example, I have an "a" 2D array, and I want to assign first index of "a" to variable "b".

This is how I code:

```
Dim a(,) As Integer = {{0, 0}, {1, 2}, {2, 4}, {3, 6}, {4, 8}}
Dim b = a(0)
```

but it raises an error "Number of indices is less than the number of dimensions of the indexed array."

How to solve this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just like you assign the values using 2D-index `{0, 0}`, you should use the same 2D-index way to get the values:

This will give you the value at the first 2D-index:

```
Dim b = a(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing a multi-dimensional array. You probably want a jagged array, which is an array whose values are arrays. A multi-dimensional array is an array with multiple dimensions, but the values are single points.

```
' array contents modified for example
' initializing multi-dimensional array
Dim multi(,) As Integer = {{0, 1}, {2, 3}}
' initializing jagged array
Dim jagged As Integer()() =
    {
        New Integer() {0, 1},
        New Integer() {2, 3}
    }
' retrieving value from multi-dimensional array
Dim multiFirst = multi(0, 0) ' equals 0
Dim multiSecond = multi(0, 1) ' equals 1
' retrieving value from jagged array
Dim jaggedFirst = jagged(0) ' equals an array with {0, 1}
Dim jaggedFirstFirst = jaggedFirst(0) ' equals 0
Dim jaggedFirstSecond = jaggedFirst(1) ' equals 1
```